# Failed to integrate Maven in eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, maven, helios

I try to integrate maven in my eclipse helios by clicking in eclipse marketplace.

But when it becomes to install software , I have this error :

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
    phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
    action=).
    Comparison method violates its general contract!
    Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

How can I resolve this please !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I assume you are running Eclipse Helios on a Machine that has a Java 7 JRE/JDK installed that is used by Eclipse. There is a known Bug that leads to this behavior because the Java Contract of the integrated sort algorithm has changed.

When you install (or use an already installed) Java 6 JRE/JDK to run Eclipse this should solve the problem.

To make sure the correct Java Installation is used for Eclipse edit the `eclipse.ini` in your Eclipse installation folder and add the following two lines at the beginning:

```
-vm
c:\<path-to-java-6>\bin\javaw.exe
```

After that all should work as expected. In newer Indigo releases this is fixed.